# Understanding an involution of the category of perverse sheaves on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, perverse-sheaves

It is well-known (for example: chapter 2 in [GGM] A. Galligo, M. Granger, P. Maisonobe. [D-modules et faisceaux pervers dont
le support singulier est un croisement normal](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AIF_1985__35_1_1_0). Ann. Inst. Fourier Grenoble,
35 (1985), 1–48) that a perverse sheaf on $X=\mathbb{C}$ with stratification $X=\mathbb{C}^\times\sqcup \{0\}$ is equivalent to the datum of $(E,F,u,v)$, where $E$, $F$ are finite dimensional vector spaces, $u:E\to F$, $v:F\to E$ are linear maps such that $1+uv$ is invertible.

There is an obvious involution on the category of such data, namely
$$(E,F,u,v)\mapsto (F,E,v,u).$$

> My question is: what is the corresponding operation on perverse sheaves?

If I understand the correspondence correctly, the case $(E,F,u,v)=(\mathbb{C},0,0,0)$ corresponds to the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb {C}}_X$, and the case $(E,F,u,v)=(0,\mathbb{C},0,0)$ corresponds to the shifted sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{C}}_0[-1]$ supported at the origin. (I am using the convention of [GGM], so in particular the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb {C}}_X$ without shift is perverse.)

Is there any interesting interpretation of this involution?

Comment: I believe it's the Fourier transform. (Say, pass from perverse sheaves to $D$-modules, then do the $D$-module Fourier transform, then go back).

Answer (score 7):

It is the Fourier–Sato transform.  You can find a detailed discussion in e.g. section 4D of this article: [Bezrukavnikov and Kapranov - Microlocal sheaves and quiver varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07050).